# Как закрыть блок при наведении на него?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, блок

```
$("#panel-click").click(function(){
    if($("#panel-click>.arrow").length==0){
        $("#panel-click>div").addClass("arrow");
        $("#panel-click").addClass("rotate");
        $('#panel').toggleClass('toggled');
    }else{
        $("#panel-click>div").removeClass("arrow");
        $("#panel-click").removeClass("rotate");
        $('#panel').removeClass('toggled');
    }
});
$("#panel").hover(function(){
    if($("#panel-click>.arrow").length==0){
        $("#panel-click>div").addClass("arrow");
        $("#panel-click").addClass("rotate");
    }else{
        $("#panel-click>div").removeClass("arrow");
        $("#panel-click").removeClass("rotate");
    }
});
```

`panel-click` - это анимированная иконка меню (hamburger). При нажатии на иконку `#panel-click` происходит ее анимация (анимируется в стрелку) и открывается блок #panel. При повторном нажатии на иконку `#panel-click` она возвращается в исходное положение и блок `#panel` закрывается. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать чтобы блок `#panel` закрывался не только при нажатии на иконку `#panel-click`, но и при наведении на сам блок `#panel`, и при этом иконка `#panel-click` возвращалась в исходное положение. Спасибо!

Comment: весь код с html сюда.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").hover(function(){
        $(".div").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.div{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #999;
  margin:10px auto;
  position:relative;
}
#hide{
  position:absolute;
  right:0; top:0;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"> 
<div id="hide"> X </div>
</div>
```

вот так - самый простой способ , пример  на [фидле](https://jsfiddle.net/g59yyqdp/)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то тебе нужно нечто подобное:

```
// событие только по наведению
$("#panel").mouseout(function(){
  // только если у панели есть класс 'toggled'
  if ($(this).hasClass('toggled')) {
    $("#panel-click>div").removeClass("arrow");
    $("#panel-click").removeClass("rotate");
    $('#panel').removeClass('toggled');
  }
});
```

Comment: Тогда не на `mouseover`, а на `mouseout`, пример исправил

Comment: Странно, давайте пример на jsfiddle